# OpenSSL RSA Sign with key from memory

Tags: delphi, openssl

I am experimenting with OpenSSL for Delphi a unit that you can find [here](http://www.disi.unige.it/person/FerranteM/delphiopenssl/index.html) . So far I am able to generate a public / private key. What I am trying to do is sign a string and then check if the string is signed with the public key.

So.. here is what I have so far. The problem is that **EVP_SignFinal** causes an access violation because **EVP_PKEY_assign** always returns pKey = nil so I guess the key is not assigned from the memory how can I assign It.

PS . You have to excuse the code is just a test ;)

Could somebody point me where I am wrong ?

```
var
  rsa : pRSA;
  eu : string;
  privateKey,publicKey,Err : pBIO;
  enc : pEVP_CIPHER;
  keylen : Cardinal;
  prv,pub : PChar;
  hash : TMD5Digest;
  mdctx : EVP_MD_CTX;
  pkey : pEVP_PKEY;
  lbuf : array [0..15] of Byte;
  i : Integer;
begin
  ERR_load_crypto_strings;
  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms;
  OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers;
  OpenSSL_add_all_digests;
  eu := 'SIGN THIS';
  enc := EVP_des_ede3_cbc;


  rsa := RSA_generate_key(1024,RSA_F4,nil,Err);
  if rsa <> nil then
  begin
  privateKey := BIO_new(BIO_s_mem);
  PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey(privateKey,rsa,enc,nil,0,nil,PChar('0PC0DE'));
  publicKey := BIO_new(BIO_s_mem);
  PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey(publicKey,rsa);
  keylen := BIO_pending(privateKey);
  GetMem(prv,keylen + 1);
  BIO_read(privateKey,prv,keylen);
  keylen := BIO_pending(publicKey);
  GetMem(pub,keylen + 1);
  BIO_read(publicKey,pub,keylen);
  Writeln(prv);
  Writeln('Keys generated!');
  pKey := nil;
  EVP_PKEY_assign(pkey,EVP_PKEY_RSA,pub);
  EVP_MD_CTX_init(@mdctx);
  EVP_SignInit(@mdctx,EVP_md5());
  EVP_SignUpdate(@mdctx,PChar(eu),Length(eu));
  EVP_SignFinal(@mdctx,@lbuf,keylen,pkey);
  EVP_MD_CTX_cleanup(@mdctx);
  WriteLn(keylen);

  Readln;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the mistake is that you are trying to sign with the public key instead of the private key. You always use the public key for encryption (and the private for decryption) and the private key for signing (and thus the public key for verification).

Furthermore, it seems to me that it is better to use `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey` instead of `EVP_PKEY_assign`, as it seems to be the direct opposite of `PEM_write_bio_RSAPrivateKey`. `EVP_PKEY_assign` seems to be a deprecated call, and is unlikely to handle PEM encoding.

Comment: switched pub with prv still the same result :(

Comment: Have you tried to use the resulting keys without writing them to file first?

Comment: `EVP_PKEY_assign` seems to be pretty old, why aren't you using methods like `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey` ?

Comment: I did that too, and I always get : error : 0906D06C : PEM_routines:PEM_read_bio: no start line!

Comment: Did you already try without writing the file? And if you do get a file, please include it in your post. It may be empty or something similar.

Comment: I am not writing it to a file I always load it from memory

Comment: Oh, sorry, I meant without the BIO call, I can see it is to memory, but you likely don't have to write it to PEM format and decode it again to use it.

Comment: I have solved it using PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey(privateKey,pKey,nil,PChar('1234567890')); but now I have a problem loading the public key and i use this by I always get error : PEM_read_bio_PUBKEY(publicKey,mKey,nil,nil);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21873/discussion-between-owlstead-and-opc0de)